# Can I use a 'Free For Personal Use' font in my cover designing portfolio?

Tags: fonts, information-graphics

Of course, the portfolio will be put up for sales as pre-mades. Is this allowed? I would be buying the font once someone requests a particular design, but until then, am I using these free fonts for Commercial Purposes? Is this a violation?

Comment: Why not ask the font designer?

Comment: If you are selling or intend to sell something that is **not** personal use.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then I gotta buy them first. Thanks for the help, guys.

Comment: What do you mean 'cover designing' and 'pre-made sales'? Typically a portfolio in the context of Graphic Design is example of your work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a legal question.

Comment: It is a good question. I think is totally on topic. But probably a bit more clarification will be handy.